# Flutter Stack Bug? Text shows over animated widget in the presence of a network image when in Stack (dartpad and web)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I created this dartpad to show what I'm seeing.
https://dartpad.dev/4bd49a19a9db745f003375e6b0e7689e

When there is a network image in a stack, it causes all of the text widgets in the stack to appear above an animated widget when they should appear below due to Stack order. (I know.  obscure, right?) However, when the network image is removed, the Stack behaves as expected.

In the dartpad, I have this Stack:

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(top: 25, child: Column(children: [Text("text below kitty")])),
        Image.network('http://placekitten.com/200/300'), // <-- COMMENT OUT THIS LINE
        Positioned(top: 50, child: Column(children: [Text("text above kitty")])),
        TopDrawer(),
        Positioned(top: 75, child: Column(children: [Text("text above drawer")])),
      ],
    );
```

Due to the placement in the stack, the kitty pic should cover the 'text below kitty' and the Topdraw() widget should cover both 'text below and text above kitty' while the 'text above drawer' is always visible. However, when the animated widget is run by pressing the burger, the "text above kitty" is visible when the cat picture is uncommented... however, when this picture is commented out, the text behaves correctly.

This seems to only be an issue with chrome and MacOS... (and dartpad)  This functioned correctly on iOS and Android. I tested this with the latest master channel code, 1.16.2-pre.41.

I believe that this is a bug, but before I submitted it, I wanted to see if I am approaching it the wrong way.

Just in case the dartpad doesn't work, here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyPage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(top: 25, child: Column(children: [Text("text below kitty")])),
        Image.network('http://placekitten.com/200/300'), // <-- COMMENT OUT THIS LINE
        Positioned(top: 50, child: Column(children: [Text("text above kitty")])),
        TopDrawer(),
        Positioned(top: 75, child: Column(children: [Text("text above drawer")])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TopDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  TopDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TopDrawerState createState() => _TopDrawerState();
}

class _TopDrawerState extends State<TopDrawer>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;
  bool _drawerState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this)
          ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 200.0).animate(controller);
    _drawerState = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: -225,
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset((animation.value * (225 / 200)), 0.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 225,
              color: Colors.pink,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(animation.value, 0.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _drawerState = !_drawerState;
                  },
                );
                _drawerState ? controller.forward() : controller.reverse();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
                color: Colors.pink,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: (animation.value / 200) * 3.14 / 4,
                  child: Icon(Icons.dehaze),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug after all, but only for flutter web and macos. 
I opened a bug report here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53078
and they’ve already accepted it as an issue.